# TFS 2010 API: Unable to Get IBuildServer from ProjectCollection Server

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to promote an existing drop and need to validate that a given Build Name/Number is valid (status and quality) before deploying the drop folder to the target environment.

Basing this off blogs like this (http://www.woodwardweb.com/dotnet/tfs_build_api_b.html) I'm trying to connect to my build server like so with no success:

```
string tfsProjectCollectionUrl = @"http://collectionServer:8080/tfs/collection";
var tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(tfsProjectCollectionUrl); 
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

IBuildServer tfsBuildServer = tfs.GetService<IBuildServer>();
//tfsBuildServer == null
```

I have two servers, Collection and Build. TFS Admin Console on Build shows "Build Service configured for collectionServer\collection". Not sure what I'm missing here.

---

Update:
I tapped my MSDN Support resources as this is somewhat time critical and made some progress by extracting these operations out to an external assembly. My method of getting the collection seemed fine, it just wasn't happy living inside the CodeActivity proper. Now, the CodeActivity calls to this external assembly and returns me my dropPathToPromote or throws an exception if status and quality conditions aren't met.

This works fine in a test harness Workflow, but not in flight. I get this error within the first 6-7 seconds of executing my build:
`Could not load file or assembly 'MyTFSAPICallingAssembly.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The new assembly is included in my Custom Assemblies VCS folder for the Build Controller to pick up, the Agent temp folders get updated with these dlls (all external assemblies and my custom ones), the new Build Definition renders the Process Template that includes this CodeActivity without exception, and other Build Definitions that reference my root custom assemblies execute without failure.

Comment: When you say with "no success", what do you mean?  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No exception, unless I try to operate on tfsBuildServer. As far as I can tell, the collection is identified just fine, just not the build server.

Comment: Whats the exception when you try to use it, GetService uses caching mechanism to optimize the usage of resources - so it might deffer execution till you actually use the service. Also it sounds that your gonna run this from build activity - if then then you should look into BuildDetail(IBuildDetail) and it should contain BuildServer, or you can grab TeamProjectCollection from it and run GetService from there or create new instance from its stored uri property. BuildDetail is available from activity context extensions (GetExtension<IBuildDetail>() or something)

Comment: Indeed I am trying to do this inside a custom CodeActivity. I was trying to avoid coupling the executing BuildDetail (Controller, Agent, etc) to the BuildDetail I'm trying to validate. In theory these could be executed from a different build server.

Comment: I try to add a watch while debugging and after the GetService is called, I have nothing in my tfsBuildServer variable. I know the build definition uri and build number I want to validate. From your GetExtension suggestion, I may be able to just get the BuildDetail with those params and not need to find the BuildServer, yes?

Comment: I brought in the TfsBuildExtensions into a sample workflow and got the BuildServer with the GetBuildServer activity. However, now I can't seem to query the builds. I get `Team Foundation services are not available from server server\Collection. 
InnerException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection'.`

Comment: The tfs connection that your got the BuildServer has been disposed of. The buildServer tries to connect to tfs using this collection, probably the scope is that of GetBuildServer activity. This all leads to believe that problem might be the way you in try to init collection. The TeamFoundationServerFactory is obsoleted in 2010 suggestion is to use TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory. For myself i have always created instances of project collection using its class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I feel like a noob-sicle. The platform on the assembly I placed my TFS API code in was marked as "x86", whereas the calling CodeActivity assembly was "Any CPU". Once that was fixed the build executed just fine. I still have some ancillary build failures to clean up, but it appears as though my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fetching the service from the projectcollection

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(@"http://collectionServer:8080/tfs/collection"));
IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing. It doesn't work in a CodeActivity for me though. The closest I can get is to put that code in an external assembly that my CodeActivity calls. But that external assembly then isn't recognized by my build controller.